# Is there any structure similar to GGM but more efficient?

Tags: pseudo-random-function, hash-tree

Although [Goldreich-Godlwasser-Micali](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/crypto/prf.html) (GGM) construction of a pseudo-random function (PRF) from a pseudo-random number generator (PRNG) is widely in many cryptographic applications, it needs to consume $2n^2$-bits of PRNG output to generate $n$-bits of PRF output.
Can we make it more efficient with other structures but preserve similar functionality to GGM structure?

Comment: Is it widely used? I would find it hard to name a single cryptographic implementation that uses this construction.